# Laravel bind data on vue tamplate

Tags: laravel, vue.js, data-binding

I am trying to bind `user_name` to Vue from this Laravel Object:

```
{ "order": [ { "id": 87, "user_id": "2", "user_name": "Mohamed Hassan", "table": 20, "total": 224, "status": 1, "delivered": 0, "paied": 0, "created_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40", "updated_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40" } ] }
```

and this object get from:

```
 {{order.data}}
```

I also tried with this:

```
 {{order.data['order']['user_name']}}
```

but it returns null

and this is my Vue template

```
<li v-for="order in orders">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><div class="notify-img">{{order.data}}</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pd-l0">
        <a href="">Date: </a>
        <a href="">{{order.created_at}}</a>
        <a href="" class="rIcon"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consilium.</p>
        <p class="time">1 Saat önce</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it properly, then the order is actually an array holding a single object.

You could try:

```
{{ order.data['order'][0]['user_name'] }}
```